# Setup in nginx will lead to security warning in Google Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, google-chrome

Since 2 days, our users get the following warning when trying to login on our service:

[image: warning]

English version:

> The information you're about to submit is not secure
>
> Because this site is using a connection that's not completely secure, your information will be visible to others.
>
> Send anyway     Go back

[image]

This is the setup in nginx we use and which worked for the last 3 years without any issue. It still works, but on Chrome it produces the warning.

```
events {

}

http {

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
  listen                443;
  server_name           server.example.com;
  client_max_body_size  100M;

  ssl on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

  ssl_certificate /etc/certs/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot



    location /ErrorPages/ {
        alias /etc/nginx/ErrorPages/;
        internal;
    }

  
   location / {

    proxy_pass          http://shinyproxy:4000; ### Übernahme der servicenamen aus Docker-compose

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;

    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    }

    location /api/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }


   location /auth/ {
   
    proxy_pass          https://keycloak:8443; ### Übernahme der servicenamen aus Docker-compose

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;

    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    }
    
}

server {
    if ($host = server.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name server.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

}
```

I found this thread:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1158169#c49

This seems to explain it. My knowledge with nginx is only quite basic, but can anyone suggest a workaround here?

Comment: You have posted the location blocks. Please post server block also. There is all the TLS stuff? Or do you use port 80?

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 1):

This warning is new in Chrome 86 and occurs when your web applicaton tries to submit a form via HTTP rather than HTTPS (or, as the bug you linked to mentions, responds to such a form submission with an HTTP redirect). Check your web application's HTML form and ensure that it posts to an HTTPS URL, not an HTTP URL, and that any redirects are to HTTPS URLs.

Comment: I updated my post with all server configs. I tried to update 

```proxy_pass          http://shinyproxy:4000``` to ```proxy_pass          https://shinyproxy:4000```, but this results in an SSL Error. What do I have to do? :/

Comment: Do you have access to source code? Change http to https? In Forms? Everywhere?

Comment: I use open source software. I placed an issue in their github repo. When changing that is enough it should be quite easy for them :-)